# How to change slider menu to custom view?

Tags: android, slider, navigation-drawer, drawer

I am new to android.I had developed an android app with a slider menu using the [library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu).

I want the menu in this way: [image]

Now I want to change slider menu to my custom xml view .How can I change this with this library?? is it possible ?? Please help me if you are familiar with this library.Thanks in advance

Comment: Start from here : http://www.michenux.net/android-sliding-menu-part-1-657.html

Comment: Post some snapshots or provide more data for what you exactly want?

Comment: check this screenshot http://smacontech.com/screenshot.png

Comment: Are you sure , you are not able to do with example on developer site ?

Comment: @ anees:I think this is better but i have only doubt about this library,How to edit new view as slider menu

Comment: Download the developer example. Edit the list view to custom cell and use that as library.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a library for navigation drawer,refer this easy example for making a sliding menu and it gives you the flexibility to make it customize the way you want :  http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html